# Unable to Add Google Cloud Messaging to Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, google-cloud-messaging

I am trying to add the **Google Cloud Messaging library** to my project in **Eclipse** (*Android Developer Tools Bundle*) but I am unable to locate the Google Cloud Messaging library in the **Android SDK Manager**.

I downloaded a new version of ADT, a few hours ago, checked for updates, it was already the latest version.

Please help me in adding this library as I need GCM for my project.

Comment: you should be using GCM that is in Google Play Services

Comment: @Spurdow I am not asking about the implementation, I have seen that page already. I want to add the library like Ravi Tamada did in that tutorial to my project from the SDK manager, however I am unable to find any such libraries under the "Extras" list. :-(

Comment: @tyczj I have already added "Google Play Services" but when I declare "GoogleCloudMessaging gcm" it doesn't recognize the class.

Comment: @RahulChowdhury oh sorry bout that, honest mistake. and that tutorial is outdated so just ignore it. :)

Comment: anyway have u tried this? "When you add the Play Services library to your project, be sure to add it with resources, as described in [Setup Google Play Services SDK](http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html#Setup)".

Comment: @spurdow No problems. :-) But do you know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

First of all make sure you have imported the google play services into your workspace.

- Go to File -> Import
- Browse to YOUR_SDK_PATH/extras/google/google_play_services/libproject/google-play-services_lib and hit OK.
- Check the **Copy projects into workspace** checkbox and hit Finish.

After this is done,

- Right click on your project and go to Properties -> Android
- In the libraries section hit the add button and select google-play-services_lib from the selection box.
- Check the **Is Library** check box and hit Apply and OK.

Hope this fixes it.

Comment: Cannot add that project, it says "No projects are found to import".

Comment: Are you able to browse into that folder from your file explorer? If yes, then try deleting that file and re-downloading the google play services library again from the SDK Manager. If it's not found then, that probably means you haven't downloaded play services yet.

Comment: Problem solved. I downloaded the **GCM.jar** from a repository, added it to my project, and everything started working. Thanks for the help though :-)